# message error "Specified cast is not valid"

Tags: c#, database

I'm trying to get information from database access with this method

```
public List<gerant> getinfogerant()
    {
        List<gerant> gerer = new List<gerant>();
        string sql_gerant = "select CIN,NOM,PRENOM,ADRESS_PERSONNEL,NUM_TEL,MAIL,MOBILE,CP_GERANT,VILLE_GERANT,DATE_CIN from GERANT";
        connexion connect = new connexion();
        OleDbConnection connection = connect.getconnexion();
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql_gerant, connection);
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       while(reader.Read())
        {
            gerer.Add(new gerant(reader.GetInt64(0),
                reader.GetString(1),
                reader.GetString(2),
                reader.GetString(3),
            reader.GetDouble(4),
                reader.GetString(5),
                reader.GetDouble(6),
                reader.GetInt32(7),
                reader.GetString(8),
                reader.GetDateTime(9))
                );

        }
        connection.Close();
        return gerer;

    }
```

In my database access I define the field `cin` as long integer and formatted "00000000"

But I'm getting an error in `reader.GetInt64(0)`:

> Specified cast is not valid

How can I solve that?

Comment: what do you mean with formatted "0000000"? if this is the result of the statement, CIN is a string.

Comment: Can the `CIN` field be `null`?

Comment: are you sure that you're getting exception in `reader.GetInt64(0)` and not in whole `gerant` constructor?

Comment: @nabuchodonossor : it's mean that the cin must be inserted in a 8digits

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov: i  change the GetInt64(0) with GetString and it works?

Comment: When you say long integer you mean bigint? Right? Sorry.. just saw that you are using Access as database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public List<gerant> getinfogerant()
{
    List<gerant> gerer = new List<gerant>();

    try
    {
        connexion connect = new connexion();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

        cmd.Connection = new OleDbConnection(connect.getconnexion());
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comd.CommandText = "select CIN,NOM,PRENOM,ADRESS_PERSONNEL,NUM_TEL,MAIL,MOBILE,CP_GERANT,VILLE_GERANT,DATE_CIN from GERANT";

        connection.Open();

        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            gerant g = new gerant();

            if (!reader.IsDBNull(0)) g.CIN = int.Parse(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(1)) g.NOM = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(2)) g.PRENOM = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(3)) g.ADRESS_PERSONNEL = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(4)) g.NUM_TEL = Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(4).ToString());
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(5)) g.MAIL = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(6)) g.MOBILE =Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(6).ToString());
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(7)) g.CP_GERANT = int.Parse(reader.GetValue(7).ToString());
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(8)) g.VILLE_GERANT = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(9)) g.DATE_CIN = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetValue(9).ToString());

            gerer.add(g);
        }
        return gerer;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

and please adjust the names of your classes and methods:
 - public List getinfogerant() -> public List getInfoGerant()

- connexion connect = new connexion(); -> connection (not x)

Answer (score 0):

Integers in Access come in 1, 2 and 4 byte varieties. The single byte number is named Byte (Range 0-255), the two-byte number is named Integer (-32768 to 32767) and then there is the Long Integer (-2 billion to 2 billion).

https://eggerapps.at/mdbviewer/docs/en/field-types.html
use getint32

Answer (score 0):

Please check for DBNULL values, might be you are getting a null value.

Regards
Jasbeer Singh

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you're getting exception not in the `reader.GetInt64(0)` but in the `gerant` constructor, so it could be any column.

To check this modify your code as follows

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var cin = reader.GetInt64(0);
            var nom = reader.GetString(1);
            var prenom = reader.GetString(2);
            var addressPersonel = reader.GetString(3);
            var numTel = reader.GetDouble(4);
            var mail = reader.GetString(5);
            var mobile = reader.GetDouble(6);
            var cpGerant = reader.GetInt32(7);
            var villeGerant = reader.GetString(8);
            var dateCin = reader.GetDateTime(9);

            gerer.Add(new gerant(cin,
                nom,
                prenom,
                addressPersonel,
                numTel,
                mail,
                mobile,
                cpGerant,
                villeGerant,
                dateCin)
                );
        }
```

And you will get exception in real line.

I recommend to check column `NUM_TEL` and `MOBILE` for `double` numbers.

Also, check non-`string` columns for `DbNull` value before reading. `long`, `int`, `double` and `DateTime` can not be null.